# right-alignment with enumitem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumitem, description

I have the following list with the `enumitem` package,

```
\begin{flushright}
\begin{description}[font=\color{black},before=\color{blue},nosep]
\item[Item:] some text some text some text
\item[Another item:] some text
\item[Very long item:] some text some text
\item[Short item:] some text some text some text
\item[Item:] some text some text
\end{description}
\end{flushright}
```

and everything works perfect, except the `flushright` environment. I want a description list with right-alignment, I mean all the lines (the label and the body in each item) aligned to the right margin. How can I do it with `enumitem` package? or do I need another package?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[font=\color{black},before=\color{blue},nosep]
  \raggedleft                           %% put this here
  \item[Item:] some text some text some text
  \item[Another item:] some text
  \item[Very long item:] some text some text
  \item[Short item:] some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
  \item[Item:] some text some text
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea about the command \raggedleft, it works perfect!